# Unable to proceed with AngularJS Material radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, material-design, angular-material

I have a project where i choose a poll (question), the next page i am presented with options/choices for those questions with a submit button and then display the results.
My aim is to materialize *or* use angular's material design guidelines. I have managed to theme the questions page and the results page. I am stuck at the choices page.
I have looked everywhere and i just cant figure out what the issue is. I could get material radio buttons to show up using  and even the choice texts beside it. I also have an error message set up where in if you hit submit without choosing an option, you get a message displayed saying 'Choose an option first'. When i hit submit after selecting a md-radio-button on the page, i keep getting the error message. I even set it up so i have a regular radio button form HTML5 and a md-radio-button besides it. Using the regular radio buttons proceeds to the next page on choice submission.

Please guide me with this.

```html
<--THIS IS REGULAR RADIO BUTTON EXAMPLE WHICH WORKS-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Choices</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>
 {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
 <form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}  
  {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
  {{ choice.choice_text }}<br>   
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="submit">

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAria', 'ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {

  };
}]);
```

```html
<--THIS IS USING MATERIAL RADIO BUTTONS ALONG WITH MY JS FILE. I HAVE NOT ATTACHED MY CSS AS THAT ISNT IMPORTANT FOR THE SOLUTION.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/styles.css">
 <title>Choices</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <h1 class="current_poll">{{ poll.question }}</h1>
 {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
 <form ng-submit="submit()" action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}  
  <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">
  {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
      <md-radio-button name="choice" value="{{ choice.id }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}<br></md-radio-button>
  {% endfor %}
  </md-radio-group>
  <form action="">
   <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised">Submit</md-button>
  </form>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how my results look. I click 3rd option (its a polls app, so correct answer doesn't matter :P) and then hit submit and see what happens.

[image: Polls_App1]

[image: Polls_App2]

Comment: What gets tarnfered to the sever when you submit? Try to check with F12 in chromw webdeveloper tools "network"

Comment: My regular radio buttons say 2 requests and processes it. But the md-radio-button says no requests caotured , reload the page to see detailed info under network. This is on click of submit. What the app does is, you have a question which is a poll, then choices of which you can select one and submit and it'll show you over all votes for that question on the next page. But I can't move to second page using angular radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You use a nested form - tag. That is not valid.

Comment: Okay, so how do I fix that? The first form tag has to have that action

Comment: Just remove the inner form tag

Comment: Okay, i cannot believe i didn't notice that. Thanks, it worked :D